# React issue with props.history.push ignore setState since setState is async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-router-dom, setstate

I have two routes here `Home` and `Result`. `Home` monitors its two states `id` and `count`. Inside `Home` there is a nested component `Page` which has a state `check` and renders a button. Button click triggers the events: 1) increment `count` if `check` is true, 2) increment `id` if `id` < 3, otherwise pass `count` to a different route `Result` (`props.history.push`).

I set `check` to `true` in order to simplify the issue in this example. Since `id` starts at 0, when Route changes, `count` should be 3 but I only got 2 here. I'm trying to synchronously call `setState` to increment the `count` first before passing it down to `Result`, but `props.history.push` ignores `setState` and executes itself.

What is the best practice to handle this or a similar situation (without modifying the component or state hierarchy)?
Find example codes and a screenshot below, please.

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/result" component={Result} />
    <Redirect from="/" to="/home" />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>;
```

Home.js

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const handleNextId = () => {
    if (id >= 3) {
      props.history.push({
        pathname: "/result",
        state: { count: count },
      });
    } else {
      setId(id + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>id: {id}</div>
      <div>count: {count}</div>
      <br />
      <Page count={handleCount} nextId={handleNextId} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Page.js

```
const Page = (props) => {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(true);

  const handleCheck = () => {
    if (check) {
      props.count();
    }
    props.nextId();
  };

  return (
    <button type="text" onClick={handleCheck}>
      next
    </button>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figure out a way to make it work by moving the `props.history.push` to `useEffect` which monitors `id` changes. Not sure if it's the best practice. Kindly let me know, please.

Home.js

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id >= 3) {
      props.history.push({
        pathname: "/result",
        state: { count: count },
      });
    }
  }, [id]);

  const handleCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const handleNextId = () => {
    setId(id + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>id: {id}</div>
      <div>count: {count}</div>
      <br />
      <Page count={handleCount} nextId={handleNextId} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

[image]

Comment: Try componentDidUpdate method in a traditional class component case.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to grab the current value to pass to history:

```
let currentCount;
setCount(current => {
   currentCount = current;
   return current;
});
props.history.push({
        pathname: "/result",
        state: { count: currentCount },
      });
```

Also you need to increment the current value:

```
setCount(current => current + 1);
```

Same idea for id.